# jquery: loading variable from another page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Could someone help me with this code?

In my Rails project I have a header that is fixed in position. One of the links is:

```
<li><%= link_to "Your Address Book", user_path(current_user), :class => 'random_number' %></li>
```

Then at the bottom of that same page I have:

```
  <script>
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

  $("random_number").click(function("#show_the_number")

           {
             alert(number);
           }
      );

   </script>
```

The code above doesn't work the way I want it to.

What I want to happen is:

//this part works ok

When the 'Your Address Book' link is clicked, load the page 'your address book' and the function 'random_number'

//here's the problem:

When the 'your address book' page loads, there's a button with id '#show_the_number'.
When this button is clicked on that new page, I want to show the alert(number) message, with the random number from the fixed header.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you are asking here is `on` delegated event..since your button is added dynamically for the click event to work you need to delegate it to its closest static parent

try this

```
 $(document).on('click',"#show_the_number",function(){
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    alert(number);
});
```

it is recommended to delegate your event to closest parent container that is present when the page is loaded rather that `document` itself.

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `.on`

example:

```
$("#IdOfParentContainer").on('click',"#show_the_number",function(){
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but every time I click a link and navigate away from 'Your Address Book' page, and then come back to it, I always get the same number '6'. I have to refresh the app to get a different number. Is there anyway the function can be called anew, each time 'Your Address Book' is clicked?

Comment: one last thing - In your example of $("#IdOfParentContainer"). etc...can I define my parent container as the div at the top of a page, one that encapsulates all other divs?

Comment: yes you can.. that is what i am trying to mention... make sure the parent div is present at the time of insertion..

Comment: you can view the link if you are confused or want to read more about the on method